# Centered label on top of checkbox

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Looking for an example of checkbox with (centered) label on top of it:

```
 IamALabel  
    [ ]
```

I'm using (ASP.NET) MVC 5 if that matters. 
I tried couple of simple things but it wouldn't center it:

```html
 <div>
      <label for="checkbox1"><span></span>IamALabel</label>
      <br/>
     <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="IamALabel" checked="checked">
    </div>
```

and also:

```html
 <div>
      <label for="checkbox1" style="display: inline-block; text-align:center"><span></span>IamALabel</label>
      <br/>
     <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="IamALabel" checked="checked">
    </div>
```

Comment: Please, show us what you've tried

Comment: @LcSalazar, I just did, my apologies as I should had done it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display: table` technique:

```css
div {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
label {
    display: table-row;
}
#chk {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="male">IamALabel</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk" />         
</div>
<div>
    <label for="male">IamALabel</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk" />         
</div>
<div>
    <label for="male">IamALabel</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk" />         
</div>
```

EDIT

For adding multiple label/checkbox near each other add `float: left` in `div` element.

Comment: Interesting, didn't think of that. However, how can I put two or more next to each other now? IamLabel1, IamLabel2, IamLabel3, etc (and checkboxes underneath)